# freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected hash

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to generate a Freemarker template, but I get:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected hash. ul evaluated instead to
    freemarker.template.SimpleSequence on line 105, column 40
    in Freemarker/MUC/UnitIndex.ftl.
```

My class:

```
public class UnitLists extends TreeSet<UnitList>
...
```

added to param as following:

```
params.put("unitLists", this.unitLists);
...
```

used in the template:

```
<#list unitLists as ul>
    <a href="${ul.linkFromRoot}" class="mya2">${ul.tag}</a>
</#list>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing a property of `ul`. Freemarker therefore expects `ul` to contain a single object, but got a `Collection` instead (a *hash* is Freemarker speech for something that maps keys to values, such as a JavaBean).

Comment: Indeed ul is also a TreeSet. I created a dummy bean containing the info I needed from ul and the issue has disappeared. Thanks.